How to setup rootless kubernetes in restricted environments
I am trying to deploy kubernetes on different machines which have some environment restrictions.
Environment

OS: RHEL 7

Control Plane Server

has root permission.
can use package manager to install packages.
share files with node servers through NFS


Node servers

no root permission
cannot use package manager
share files with control place server through NFS
does not have write permission to /var, /etc,


Tools I chose

container runtime: containerd
container: podman



Progress
I tried to follow the rootless instruction on Official Guide
and finished install my control plane server. However I am stuck in installing nodes.
Method I tried
I can download kubeadm and kubelet on node servers, but I cannot setup kubeadm and kubelet which need root permission according to official guide.
kubeadm

Cannot close swapoff
Cannot set /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward to 1

kubelet

need to start as a service through systemctl  -> Cannot use systemctl

Is there any approach to setup node servers without root permissions?
